# java_version attribute is not working as expected in applet while opening applet with IE

Tags: java, applet

My applet code is below

```
  <html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<APPLET width="500" height="500">
 <PARAM name="code" value="myJavaAssistPack.TestApplet">
 <PARAM name="archive" value="myApplet.jar">
 <param name="java_version" value="1.7*">
</APPLET>
</body>
</html>
```

When I am launching applet it should show warning like "unsupported java version required: " because in my machine java 1.7 is not installed. Having only 1.6_33 jdk. But it is not showing this message and applet is opening fine with 1.6. Why?

Comment: Why code an applet?  If it is due to the teacher specifying it, please refer them to [Why CS teachers should **stop** teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/).